# "Radcliffe Wave" & filamentary dust structures

Tags: galaxy

A recent paper by [Joao Alves et al](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.08748) describes a kpc-long dust filament with a long, thin dust structure with vertical sinusoidal wave component. From the limited art work that accompanies it, this structure appears to be one of those elongated filamentary dust clouds that lie on the interior shear surfaces of spiral waves and fore sides of galactic bars. Images of spiral galaxies with large scale arms reveal these dust filaments to be numerous and homomorphic. A number of studies, e.g. [Hennebelle & Inutsuka](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fspas.2019.00005/full) and [Gritschneder et al](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.00378v3) describe the properties of dust filaments in general. My question is whether kpc-scale elongated filaments along shear surfaces can in fact act as magnetic flux tube loci for multiple-generation GMC collapse into linear cluster complexes e.g. M16, M17, M8, etc. Can anyone recommend studies that address these issues?